# Equivalence of a Levy measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, levy-processes

We know that a measure $\nu$ is a Levy measure if:
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{1}
    \nu(\{0\}),\quad \int_{|x|<1}|x|^{2} \nu (dx) <\infty, \quad \int_{|x| \geq 1}  \nu (dx)<\infty. 
\end{equation}
It straightforward to show that
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
    \int \frac{|x|^2}{1+ |x|^2} \nu (dx) < \infty
\end{equation}
But how to show that (*) implies (\ref{1}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|x| \leq 1$,
$$|x|^2 - \frac{|x|^2}{1 + |x|^2} = \frac{|x|^4}{1 + |x|^2} \leq \frac{|x|^2}{1 + |x|^2} \in L^1(\nu).$$
So the first integral is finite.
For $|x| \geq 1$,
$$1 - \frac{|x|^2}{1 + |x|^2} = \frac{1}{1 + |x|^2} \leq \frac{|x|^2}{1 + |x|^2} \in L^1(\nu).$$
So the second integral is finite.

However, we might have $\nu(\{0\}) = \infty$. For example, let $\nu(\{0\}) = \infty$, $\nu(\{0\}^c) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interestingly, some books define a Levy measure by imposing $\nu(\{0\})$.